# Find the doctor with the max. number of medical attentions

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get the id of the doctor who performed the max. number of medical attentions:

The table I'm working with has these columns:

```
Adm_ID //Id of the Attention
Med_ID //Medical Procedure carried out
Doc_ID //ID Doctor
```

This is my attempt:

First I count the number of attentions a doctor has:

```
SELECT Doc_ID, COUNT(*) AS Attentions
FROM Adm_Med
GROUP BY Doc_ID
```

Then I find the maximum between them

```
SELECT MAX(Attentions)
FROM
(
SELECT Doc_ID, COUNT(*) AS Attentions
FROM Adm_Med
GROUP BY Doc_ID
) temp
```

And now I'm having troubles. It would be nice if I can get the Doc_ID and the Attentions simultaneously, but when a query something like

```
SELECT MAX(Attentions), Doc_ID
FROM
(
SELECT Doc_ID, COUNT(*) AS Attentions
FROM Adm_Med
GROUP BY Doc_ID
) temp
```

I get an error (Column 'temp.Doc_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause).

So instead I'm trying to query the innermost table with columns Doc_ID and Attentions again and matching the Attentions with the Max(Attentions):

```
SELECT Doc_ID
FROM
(
SELECT Doc_ID, COUNT(*) AS Attentions
FROM Adm_Med
GROUP BY Doc_ID
) t1,
(
SELECT MAX(Attentions) AS Maxattentions, 
FROM
(
SELECT Doc_ID, COUNT(*) AS Attentions
FROM Adm_Med
GROUP BY Doc_ID
) temp
)t2
WHERE t1.Attentions=t2.Maxattentions
```

Which is (ugly) and gives again an error.

I have no idea how to get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be simplified by using `TOP 1` and `Order By`

```
SELECT TOP 1 Doc_ID, COUNT(*) AS Attentions
FROM Adm_Med
GROUP BY Doc_ID
Order by Attentions desc
```

In case there is a *tie* in max Count and you want all the tie records then use `TOP 1 with Ties`

```
SELECT TOP 1 with Ties Doc_ID, COUNT(*) AS Attentions
FROM Adm_Med
GROUP BY Doc_ID
Order by Attentions desc
```